# Raven's matrix puzzle: 3x3 grids of suits

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

I found this puzzle on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Who-can-solve-this-Ravens-Progressive-matrix-test) and it was pretty hard:

[image: Progressive matrix puzzle]

Can someone help! The solution makes no sense to me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

> A

because:

Two rules can be inferred that are both needed to single it out.

Rule 1:

> If you think row-wise, in each column of the tile there can be two shapes that is able to be paired up with two shapes (at most) of the same shape in the same column of the tile next to it. This is considering if each shape can be **paired off with only one other shape at the same time**. This eliminates B,C,D,E,F and H.

Here is a visual representation of what I am on about:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Rule 2:

> With each tile there has to be at least one row in that tile where all the shapes are different. This eliminates G so we have A as the final option.

Here is picture of the first row for example to show what I am on about:

> [image]

Comment: Dang that was quick. Let's hear what others have got to say.

Comment: IIUC you are saying that there is a whole category of answers that satisfy the criterion you found and answer 'A' is just one example of that category. But I would expect an answer that can be derived even if no options were given.